# need to get rel attribute and href attribute when making a while div clickable in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hey there, having some issues passing parameter values in jQuery. I need a div to open a link that opens as a Shadowbox dialog .. (Shadowbox uses the rel tag) i therefore need to get the value of both the href and rel, but cant' figure it out. i tried to just add .attr("rel") to the string but that didnt work.

My jquery:

```
$("div.banner").click(function() {  
     window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;     });
```

thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but if you wanted to use both the rel and href attributes when building the window.location string, you'd need to do something like this.

```
$("div.banner").click(function() {
    var $link = $(this).find("a");
    window.location = $link.attr("href") + $link.attr("rel");
    return false;
});
```